# Facebook Fan-Box / Likebox height problem stream

Tags: facebook, facebook-likebox

I would like to integrate FB Fan-Box on my website. Everything works fine, except the height is not correct. For me, the important thing is not displaying the faces, but the stream. When I adjust the height parameter the whole frame gets bigger, but the layer with the stream in it remains still 300px. How can I set this to 900px, since I would like my visitors to see more activities on the stream?!

Here is my code:

```
<iframe 
   src="http://www.facebook.com/plugins/likebox.php?href=http%3A%2F
%2Fwww.facebook.com%2Fapps%2Fapplication.php%3Fid%3D200876329955648&amp;width=800&
amp;colorscheme=light&amp;show_faces=false&amp;border_color&amp;stream=true&
amp;header=false&amp;height=900" 
    scrolling="no" 
    frameborder="0" 
    style="border:none; overflow:hidden; width:800px; height:900px;"
    allowTransparency="true"></iframe>
```

Thanks for the help!!!!

Comment: This is a common question, and I haven't found an authoritative answer. Not only that, but FB seems to change the platform quietly from time to time, which results in the phenomenon that previous suggestions from the community on how to do this that worked at one time, no longer work now. If you look in the static .css for the likebox.php, you will see a `.page_stream { height:300px;}` which as far as I know, cannot be simply overridden. Still searching.

Answer (score 0):

Try the HTML5 version, it may work better:

```
<div 
  class="fb-like-box" 
  data-href="http://www.facebook.com/platform" 
  data-width="292" 
  data-height="900" 
  data-show-faces="false" 
  data-stream="true" 
  data-header="false">
</div>
```

I've verified that it will go to 900 in height showing more stream items.

Answer (score 0):

No it is not for my HTML 5 tag with 2000px

```
<div class="fb-like-box" 
                 data-width="1100"
                 data-height="2000"
```

Facebook generate iframe height correctly, but inside the iframe 
it explicitly set div to 300px... This is a very annoying bug

```
<iframe name="f36c389328" width="1100px" height="2000px"
<html>
..
<div class="phm pluginLikeboxStream" style="height: 300px"> <---
```

What is a point of having it configurable if it is defaulted to 300px on FB side?